# Which django package can I use for REST API building?

Tags: python, django, rest

Which Django package can I use for REST API building? Previously I have used Piston but seems days have changed and people not are recommending Piston. Is there any other solution that can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pydanny.com/choosing-an-api-framework-for-django.html may be of interest.

Comment: Piston development is dead, which is why no one's recommending it. TastyPie is the best and most feature-rich package for the time-being.

Answer (score 3):

Tasty pie is fine: http://tastypieapi.org/

However, you may find it easier to just write the views by hand. I've found little advantage in using it.